# find and index equal values in multidimensional matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, indexing, equality

I am producing a three dimensional matrix with two rows(e.g. a `2x1000x10` matrix). These contain x- and y-coordinates for dot motion paths, where the first line contains the x-coordinates and the second line the y-coordinates. The number of columns (here: 1000) depends on the length of the motion paths. The number of levels in the third dimension depends on the number of dots (here: 10).

I want to know if some dots are going to overlap, i.e. if any x- and y-coordinates across the third dimension at the same time point t, i.e. any combination of `(:, t, :)`, are identical. So the comparison will be within the matrix.

```
i = [1:size(matrix, 3)];
j = [1:size(matrix, 3)];
t = [1:size(matrix, 2)];

crash = any(coordinates(:, t, i)==coordinates(:, t, j))
```

would be trivial because `i` and `j` can be the same and thus say that the point is equal to itself.

Do you know how I can detect equal value combinations across matrix dimensions? How do I index them if they exist?

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want. To **find out if there's a crash**:

```
t = bsxfun(@eq, coordinates, permute(coordinates, [1 2 4 3]));
crash = any(sum(any(all(t,1),2),4)>1,3);
```

We first use [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to compute a 4D array (`t`) that tests for equality in the same coordinate (1st dim) and the same position along path (2nd dim), where the 3rd and 4th dims run over all pairs of dots. A crash occurs if both coordinates (`all(,...,1)`) are equal for any column (`any(...,2)`) in more than one "other" dot (`sum(...,4)>1`) for any "reference" dot (`any(...,3)`). We need to specify "more than one" because any dot is at least equal to itself (for a given position and coordinate).

Example:

```
>> coordinates = randi(9,2,5,4)
coordinates(:,:,1) =
     7     4     3     3     8
     7     1     4     2     4
coordinates(:,:,2) =
     8     7     8     4     8
     4     4     7     2     9
coordinates(:,:,3) =
     3     4     7     8     5
     7     8     2     9     8
coordinates(:,:,4) =
     6     2     7     8     5
     2     4     8     3     1

>> t = bsxfun(@eq, coordinates, permute(coordinates, [1 2 4 3]));
>> crash = any(sum(any(all(t,1),2),4)>1,3)
crash =
     0

>> coordinates(:,2,4) = coordinates(:,2,1) %// 4th dot equal to 1st dot in column 2
coordinates(:,:,1) =
     7     4     3     3     8
     7     1     4     2     4
coordinates(:,:,2) =
     8     7     8     4     8
     4     4     7     2     9
coordinates(:,:,3) =
     3     4     7     8     5
     7     8     2     9     8
coordinates(:,:,4) =
     6     4     7     8     5
     2     1     8     3     1

>> t = bsxfun(@eq, coordinates, permute(coordinates, [1 2 4 3]));
>> crash = any(sum(any(all(t,1),2),4)>1,3)
crash =
     1
```

---

To **find the coordinates** of the crash:

```
t = bsxfun(@eq, coordinates, permute(coordinates, [1 2 4 3]));
[m,n,p] = size(coordinates);
ii = find(squeeze(all(bsxfun(@times, t, ...
    bsxfun(@ne, reshape(1:p, 1,1,[]), reshape(1:p, 1,1,1,[]) )),1)));
[col, dot_ref, dot_oth] = ind2sub([n p p], ii);
```

In the latter example, this gives

```
col =
     2
     2
dot_ref =
     4
     1
dot_oth =
     1
     4
```

which tells you that the dot 4 equals dot 1 in column 2; and then of course that dot 1 equals dot 4 in column 2.

This computes the same `t` as above. It then multiplies by a logical mask along the third and fourth dimensions (`bsxfun(@ne, reshape(1:p, 1,1,[]), reshape(1:p, 1,1,1,[]) )`) to avoid detecting each dot as similar to itself. Finally, it requires that all coordinates (`all(...,1)`) be the same in order to declare two dots as crashing, and applies [`find`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to locate those dots. The result (`ii`) is a linear index into a 3D array of dimensions path length × number of dots × number of dots, which is translated by [`ind2sub`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) into position along path and identities of crashing dots.

Comment: Thanks for `bsxfun`ning this. Much faster than my loopy solution. Does this return the coordinates of the crash as well?

Comment: Are you sure that's the output for `ii` and `jj`?

Comment: @IKavanagh I've changed my code for coordinates. Two more `bsxfun`s :-)

Comment: Much better :) but now there's 2 more `bsxfun`s I've to figure out :(

Comment: @IKavanagh Sorry, I'll try to find some time later in the day to add an explanation!

Comment: I guess you now have the same functionality as my answer, except that yours goes like lighting compared to my bicycle.

Comment: @IKavanagh Explanation added!

Answer (score 0):

```
A=[1 2 ;3 4];B=[5 6;3 9];
A==B
ans =
     0     0
     1     0
```

This works in 2D, but also in 3D. You can find the location of the equal numbers by using `find`:

```
C=permute(A,[3 2 1]);
D=permute(B,[3 2 1]);
find(C==D)
ans =
     3
```

where `3` is a linear index to the location of the equal number.

```
for ii = 1:size(A,3)-1
    for jj = ii+1:size(A,3)
        [r{ii,jj},c{ii,jj},v{ii,jj}] = find(squeeze(A(:,:,ii))==squeeze(A(:,:,jj)));
    end
end
```

This will loop over your matrices in the third dimension, i.e. your physical dots. It will squeeze out the 2D matrix per dot and check that against every other dot's 2D matrix. If it finds any, it will store the row, column and value at the intersection in the cells `r`, `c` and `v`, where the indices correspond to the dot numbers, i.e. `r{2,4}` will give the row numbers of intersections between dot 2 and 4.

Comment: Thank you, Adriaan. However, I want to know if there are similarities *within* the matrix and not if one of these matrices is at some point equal to any other matrix.

Comment: So you want to know whether two points in the third dimension (your dots) are colliding?

Comment: Yes. Kind of. There are 10 movement paths in the same matrix. So I need to know if they collide/ have identical coordinates at a certain time point.

Comment: You need `any(squeeze(A(:,:,1))==squeeze(A(:,:,2)));`, I'll type up a solution in a sec